# Subquery returned more than 1 value when using Union and string_split()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that will insert data in a table using UNION.

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE
(
  ID smallint,
  ACode varchar(64)
)

INSERT INTO @testTable
SELECT 1, 'A1,B2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C1,D2'


SELECT [value] As ACode
FROM STRING_SPLIT
(
  (
    SELECT t.ACode
    FROM @testTable t
  ),
  ','
)
```

I don't encounter problems when there is only a single row that I need to return. I am expecting that when there is two or more UNION it will just append at the end, but it gives me an error. *"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression*."

Can anyone help me to fix my query?

I am expecting something like this :
[image]

[DEMO SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d61310f750e4da6368685642adfa6079)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CROSS APPLY` instead

**Example**

```
Select ACode=B.value
 From  @testTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(ACode,',') B
```

**Results**

```
ACode
A1
B2
C1
D2
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, is Cross apply is almost the same with inner join?

Comment: @Amelia I like to think about CROSS APPLY as a record level sub-routine